# OL3 offline mapping

Tags: openlayers-3

I have problem how to coonnect a offline tileLayer in ol3.
This ismy code:

> var tileLayer = new ol.source.XYZ("offline",
>   "Tiles/${x}/${y}/${z}.png", { numZoomLevels: 18, isBaseLayer: true });

It was work fine in ol2 with OpenLayers.Layer.OSM
I spend some time looking for help, but I found a wall.

Answer (score 0):

First you define a tile layer ([ol.layer.Tile](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html)) and inside this you define the source.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 1,
        center: [0, 0]
    }),
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'Tiles/{x}/{y}/{z}.png',
                maxZoom: 18
            })
        })
    ]
});
```

**Edited the url of the ol.source.XYZ object, moved out the $ chars. Maybe now your tiles will load.**

Comment: Thank You fo Your answear, now it is working better (no error in script) but I stil I can't see my tiles (I put a tiles from open street map to Tile folder in this samem place where i have my index.html page with ol3 map.)

Comment: Yes, I tried to do this earlier (and more other diifrent option), but did not work. But I appretiate your  answear, maybe any others option I don't know. Meanwhile I coming back to ol2.